# Atom Run F# script, Windows 7 error

Tags: f#, windows-7-x64, atom-editor

I am trying to run F# script from Atom editor but kept on getting the following error:

> Unable to run fsi is it in your path?

I've checked the environment variables and the path is set correctly and can run it from the command prompt. Also others suggested running Atom from command prompt, I did that but still the same. Is Atom looking for files in a case sensitive way? (If so that may be the issue as the F# interactive is "Fsi.exe").

Comment: Have you tried to restart editor after adding fsi to path?

Comment: I'd probably report this on GitHub too: https://github.com/fsprojects/atom-fsharp